# PHP question about adding hyphens to words

Tags: php

I was wondering if some one enters a tag like `ruby on rails` is there a way I can add a hyphen to the white spaces between the words for example `ruby-on-rails` using PHP.

Comment: Help yourself: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php It's a lot quicker to look up the solution in the online PHP manual than to ask people for the answer to basic problems like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the current policy is, but when this site started beginner questions were explicitly encouraged.

Comment: Sure, beginner questions should be encouraged, but so should personal initiative. You can't learn a language without being self-motivated to learn it. That means consulting the documentation first before you start asking people for help. Also, the biggest problem beginners often face is not knowing what online resources are available to them. It's a bit impractical to ask a question on StackOverflow every time you need to look up a PHP function. The PHP.net function search OTOH is very effective and an invaluable resource for specifically this type of question.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're asking a different question, but lacking more context ...

```
$string = 'ruby on rails';
$string_with_dashes = str_replace(' ','-',$string);
```

should get you where you want to go.

Comment: what kind of question do you think I'm asking?

Comment: @helpMe, the kind in which the answer is different from the one Alan posted.

Comment: It sounded like you might be using some third party tagging library and you might want to have it add the hyphens automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this:

```
$tag = 'ruby on rails';
$newTag = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($tag));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'ruby on rails'; // your entered tag
$myTag = trim($str); // remove extra spaces from beginning and end     
$hyphenTag = str_replace( ' ', '-', $myTag ); // place '-' between words
echo $hyphenTag; // print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess

```
$s = strtolower(trim($s));
$s = str_replace(" ","-",$s);
$s = preg_replace('![^a-z0-9-]!',"",$s);
$s = preg_replace('!\-+!',"-",$s);
```