# How can I use in .htaccess?

Tags: php

I want to change from this address:

```
www.domain.com/game.php?id=1
```

to somthing like that:

```
www.domain.com/game/1/THE-NAME-OF-THE-GAME-IN-DB
```

How can I do it?

And one more question:

I want when the user goes to address which doesnt exists, for example if it doesnt exists:

```
www.domain.com/game.php?id=9123912 - this ID doesnt exists
```

The server will pass him to 404 error. How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

game.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $row = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = '{$_GET['id']}'"));

    if ($row) {
        $game = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = '{$_GET['id']}'"));
        Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
        Header( "Location: /game/".$game['id']."/".seo_title($game['name'])); 
    } 

    else {
        Header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not found" ); 
    }

    exit;
}
```

htaccess:

```
LIKE YOU SAID. I JUST COPIED.
```

Comment: do you have  `id` and `name` columns in your table? aren't they `game_title` or something?

Comment: note that you should sanitize $_GET['id'] with at least `$_GET['id'] = intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: you don't need another SQL call. why not to get array instead of just num rows?

Comment: No, your guess was successful :-)
Its not important if the seo_title is hebrew.. do I right? because anyway it doesnt write the id..

your #2+#3 comments - I thing it doesnt imporant.. $game have to work anyway.

Comment: it is important for any language. if it's different from latin, you have to search a translit function for your language and add it to seo_title() function

Comment: Ok, but why isnt the id working?

Comment: dunno. Something wrong with your query. I am sure you have such a query down in your script. why not to just copy a code from there?

Comment: Even I write: Header( "Location: /game/3"); it passes me to /game//. lol.

Comment: Oh now it is working!
Thank you. I just chageed things..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([0-9]+)/ /game.php?newid=$1
```

game.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $row = dbgetrow("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = %s",$_GET['id']);
  if ($row) {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: /game/".$row['id']."/".seo_title($row['name'])); 
  } else {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not found" ); 
  }
  exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['newid'])) $_GET['id'] = $_GET['newid'];
```

this is a code, that works for me but considered to be a pseudo-code to give you an idea.
dbgetrow() function to get a row from the database
and seo_title() function could be like this one

```
function seo_title($s) {
    $s = strtolower(trim($s));
    $s = str_replace(" ","-",$s);
    $s = preg_replace('![^a-z0-9-]!',"",$s);
    $s = preg_replace('!\-+!',"-",$s);
    return $s;
}
```

The whole concept has been pinched from SO :)
the only `games/1/` part is really important while the rest can be anything, game title is just for seo purpose. Take this question title for example:
[How can I use in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439430/not-really-a-question-title-lol)
:)

Comment: Hey, first - thank you!
It passes me to - www.domain.com/game// - why?
and what is this $newid?
thank you.

Comment: @Luis this is a code, that works for me but considered to be a pseudo-code to give you an idea. substitute a `dbgetrow()` function with database lookup and actual variables with your own field names. $newid for not to mess new seo links with old ones. onse your script gets $_GET['newid'] that means it's called with new link. and once with $_GET['id'] - it was called with old game.php?id=1 link and should be rewritten, with proper new address, `/game/1/THE-NAME-OF-THE-GAME-IN-DB` one. To make it, you have to fill an address template with data from DB

Comment: and possible seo_totle() function contents I've posted recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437537/php-question-about-adding-hyphens-to-words/3437692#3437692

Comment: I changed the functions.. of course. Im working with PHP.
The part of $row works.. the part of seo_title(), which function it is?

Comment: Hmm.. again, its pass me to: www.domain.com/game//
I am editing the question and I show you how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess isn't meant to perform url rewriting like you mention. If your server is running apache try [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). If your server is running IIS try [this](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).

As for the second question, if the id doesn't exist, have game.php perform a redirect to a pagename you know does not exist (like 9123912.html). The server should be configured to deliver the 404 natively then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what he wants is *exactly* what URL rewriting is commonly used for - he's just stated it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to redirect page to correct url like code below:*(work for me)*

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$script_url = "http://localhost/scripts/myscripts/";
  $row = dbgetrow("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = %s",$_GET['id']);
  if ($row) {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    Header( "Location: ".$script_url."/game/".$row['id']."/".seo_title($row['name'])); 
  } else {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not found" ); 
  }
}
```

and in .htaccess file you can also set `RewriteBase` to somethings like `RewriteBase /` or `RewriteBase /YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH_WITHOUT_HOST_NAME/`

also see [Apache Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase)