# how to generate a new url for a new page in php

Tags: php, url, web

If we don't use the frameworks, then how to generate a new url in PHP for a new page which may be created dynamicly by the users?
For example, a user may create a new account or post a new pice of article, then we'll allocate a specific url for the user, just like http://www.a.com/username/article/2011231.php.
My question is how to generate the specific number 2011231 and the whole url?

Comment: How are you doing any of it behind the scenes?

Comment: I believe you are actually keeping those articles in a database!! You can assign an URL there!

Comment: frameworks are simply collections of tools. they don't do anything that can't be done without frameworks... they just (sometimes) make it easier.

Comment: @Broncha yes, no doubt that the articles are all in the database. but just take this stackoverflow page for example, stackoverflow.com/questions/10527173/

Comment: Google or SO search for "pretty URLs" and "URL rewriting". Those URLs are just redirected internally to a script that handles them, you're not actually "generating" them.

Comment: how the web created this link ?

Comment: @deceze you mean url rewriting? got it~ i'll look it up~:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty URL's for web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142095/pretty-urls-for-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is pretty-urls

You need to use URL rewrite.

You need to save the articles with an appropriate URL in the database. Say a user creates an article `How to bake a cake`. You would store a pretty url for this article in your `article` table like `how-to-bake-a-cake`. You are gonna need some mechanism to convert title to these pretty URLs

The say in the front end you have `article.php`

The default working of `article.php` is `example.com/article.php?url=how-to-bake-a-cake`

In the `article.php` you would find the article with the privided prettyurl and display it.

Now you would use `.htaccess` to actually have a URL like `example.com/article/how-to-bake-a-cake`

In your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^article/(.*)
RewriteRule article.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, that URL is composed of the date in the format yearmonthday.php. If that is what you want to copy, you can use `date('Ymd')`. Assuming, on the other hand, you want an incrementing number and you store articles in a database, simply run your `INSERT` command and then use the `mysql_insert_id()` function after that to get the ID. You would then need an Apache rewrite to rewrite /username/article/[number].php to a PHP file that would look up that article in the database and display it, something like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/username/article/(\d*)\.php$ /articles.php?articleid=$1
```

Which would take, for instance, a request for `http://domain.com/username/article/12345.php` and send it to `/articles.php?articleid=12345`. From there, `$_GET["articleid"]` would contain the ID. If you also needed the PHP script to know the username, you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/article/(\d*)\.php$ /articles.php?username=$1&articleid=$2
```

Then `$_GET["username"]` would have the username and `$_GET["articleid"]` would have the article ID.